# playback in reverse chronological order

Tags: soundcloud

**Soundcloud** is incredible. Compared to all other music-oriented sites, as a computer science major and a die-hard music fan, I can assuredly say Soundcloud is a beautiful creation, in terms of both purpose and design. Onto my (rudimentary and somewhat secondary) idea:

I feel it would be beneficial for Soundcloud to have a feature which allows for reverse playback - not in terms of playing song files themselves in reverse, but in reverse chronological order. Including this option would simply be a matter of a toggleable (probably not a real word) `i--` vs. `i++` and an additional conditional.

Doing so would allow for users to listen through their favorites in order of oldest to newest, to understand the development of artists over time, etc. While this isn't necessarily IMPORTANT, I think it extremely utilitarian, especially when programs like iTunes offer the option to sort by date added/modified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature suggestion for a third-party product, and not specifically about software development.

Comment: @JeremyCaney agreed, it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old post here but the behavior of SoundCloud hasn't changed so this question is still relevant in my opinion. SoundCloud playlists, including the "liked tracks" playlist, still behave the same way as today. When listening to a playlist, the player always starts with the same song: the one you first added when you created the list. The track you just recently discovered will always be played last. It's a tad annoying and there is currently no way of reversing this order.

I created a custom SoundCloud player a while ago to answer this specific issue. You can try it here: https://alexandre.abrioux.fr/sc/.

The code is open-source: https://github.com/alexandre-abrioux/soundcloud-reverse.

I hope this will help some of you. Feel free to enjoy your playlists in reverse chronological order, or even fork the project and create your own player. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the created_at timestamp of the /tracks resource in the API.

Your question might better be directed at programmers.stackexchange.com as this site is more for specific code-related troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Like HeatherSpence said, you can use the API to construct your own player (perhaps reverse-soundcloud.com ??), or just make a playlist in whatever order you like.